# Tensor and Vector Notation

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, tensors, general-relativity

I'm given the tensor $X^{\mu\nu}$ and vector $V^\mu$ of the form
$$X^{\mu\nu} = \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix},\quad V^{\mu} = (-1,2,0,-2)$$
and I need to find the components of $X^\mu_{\,\,\,\nu}$, $X_\mu^{\,\,\,\nu}$, $X^{(\mu\nu)}$, $X_{[\mu\nu]}$, etc and I just have no idea what this notation even means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the raising/lowering of indices, and the symmetrization/antisymmetrization of tensors.

I'm not certain as to why you have the vector $V$, but I'm going to assume a follow up question of what does $X_{i}^{\;j}V^i$ mean?  Since I'll be using that notation at first, I'll go ahead and explain it.

Given some covector $\omega_i$ and some vector $V^j$, the pairing of the two, write
$$(\omega,V)=\omega_iV^i=\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_iV^i,$$
so we're using the Einstein summation convention.

If you have a bilinear form $g_{ij}$ and vector $V^i$, then the pairing induces a covector for the form
$$\omega_j=g_{ij}V^i=\sum_{i=1}^ng_{ij}V^i.$$

If one is given an inner product $g_{ij}$ , we use the same symbol to represent our new covector, so in the above example, we write
$$V_j=g_{ij}V^i.$$

This then generalizes in the natural way to any tensor:
$$X^i_{\;j}:=g_{jk}X^{ik},$$
and similarly,
$$X_i^{\;j}:=g_{ik}X^{kj}.$$

The symmetrization of a tensor $X^{ij}$ is given by
$$X^{(ij)}=\frac{1}{2}(X^{ij}+X^{ji}),$$
and the antisymmetrization is given by
$$X^{[ij]}=\frac{1}{2}(X^{ij}-X^{ji}).$$

If you're not given an inner product $g_{ij}$, it's probably assume to the Euclidean one $\delta_{ij}$ (the Kroncker Delta, written as the identity matrix in matrix form).

Typically any first course book on differential geometry should cover basic tensorial manipulations on a vector space.  I believe Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds has an entire chapter dedicated to this before jumping into tensor bundles.

**Edit:**

For a brief introduction to tensors.  Let $V$ be a real vector space, and let $V^*$ denote it's dual space (the space of all linear functionals $V\to\mathbb{R}$, which we call covectors).  Then one can think of an inner product, $g$, as a symmetric, positive-definite, bilinear form on $V$, that is, $g:V\times V\to\mathbf{R}$. A tensor generalizes this notion.  A tensor of $T$ of rank $(k,l)$ is a multilinear map
$$T:(V^*\times V^*\times\cdots\times V^*)\times(V\times V\times \cdots\times V)\to\mathbf{R},$$
where there are $k$ copies of $V^*$ in the above, and $l$ copies of $V$.

Essentially, a $(k,l)$-tensor is just a real-valued map that that "eats" $k$ covectors and $l$ vectors and "spits out" a real number.  Many tensor manipulations occur, when these tensors *don't* eat enough covectors or vectors.  For example, we have our inner product $g$, and it "eats" a vector $V$, then it still has room to "eat" one more vector before giving a real number.  This is equivalent to a covector, and the definition of $V_j=g_{ij}V^i$ as a covector.

Comment: My course in differential geometry didn't mention tensors but now doing GR I'm being thrown in. So is it right that
$$\Large X^\mu_{\,\,\,\nu} = g_{\nu\sigma}X^{\mu\sigma} = X^{\mu\sigma}g_{\nu\sigma} = X^{\mu\sigma}g_{\sigma\nu}$$
as $g_{\nu\sigma}$ is symmetric but I don't see what to do with this? What is $g_{\sigma\nu}$ as a matrix? @Matt

Comment: Yes, $g_{\mu\nu}$ can be represented as a (symmetric) matrix, where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the coefficient in the $(\mu,\nu)$-th entry.  This manipulation of $g_{\nu\sigma}X^{\mu\sigma}$ is just matrix multiplication, but written in a much more concise way.

Comment: A tensor is just a multilinear map on a vector space.  I'll edit my answer with a small introduction to such.